# self.assertQuerysetEqual( response.context['latest_question_list'], ['<Question: Past question.>'] )

Tags: django

I encountered this line in the following tutorial

`self.assertQuerysetEqual( response.context['latest_question_list'], ['<Question: Past question.>'] )`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/

`['<Question: Past question.>']` Where is this snippet from?

I understand  that `response.context['latest_question_list']` returns a list of objects. Why is it being compared to `['<Question: Past question.>']`?

Comment: @ Python Newbie  it is the output, in ```django``` you will get ```queryset``` when you call some functions like ```filter```, ```all``` and so on.

Comment: @iliya, I do not see how my question is related to queryset. May you please elaborate?

Comment: @ Python Newbie ```['<Question: Past question.>']``` this is a query and you are testing this against the first argument, this is written manually and it is also the form of your ```model``` , in this scenario ```Question```

Comment: @iliya, you are right!  The brackets confused me as I was not familiar with queryset format. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ Python Newbie  I will put that as n answer that may help other as help.

Answer (score 1):

The part you are confused about, is a `query`(`['<Question: Past question.>']`)  written by hand to check against the first part.